# Regexp whitespace excluding strings

Tags: php, regex

I`m looking for an regular expression that matches all whitespace and line breaks (\s) but not matching whitespace between quotes (double or simple) . Example :

```
a = b //matches 2 whitespaces a*=*b
a = "my test" // matches 2 whitespaces too a*=*"my test" (ignoring all whitespaces , lines breaks,etc between quotes.)
a = "my test", a = b , c = "my another string " // matches 9 (excluding strings whitespace)
```

Any help ?

Comment: Can you have multiple pairs of quotes ? And if so, can they be nested ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code writing service. What efforts have you made to solve this problem yourself before posting here?

Comment: You['re mistaken. This is my site. I'm a registered user here, and users moderate this site. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] pages. You don't get to say who comments or answers you here. Once again, *what effort have you made to solve this problem yourself first before posting?*

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should work fine :
`?![^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*$)`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/D66tb1/1)
Note that the regex starts with a space, I didn't use `\s`, so it matches only spaces and not tabulations or linebreaks.
The regex means match any space that is not followed by an odd number of quotes.
Also, don't forget to use the `m` flag